Break the loop if stdin has value
I can not stop the loop if there is not  a gap in data send via UART.
If there is gap in data it listens to the command but does not read the UART data anymore.
I would like to
I read data on UART and display the message. If keyboard input (stdin) is send  I would like to stops to read the data from UART and write the message which was send via stdin to UART.
something like msvcrt.kbhit() in real python.
example of my code
uart = UART(0, baudrate=115200, tx=Pin(0), rx=Pin(1))
uart.init(bits=8, parity=None, stop=1)

utime.sleep(0.5)
keyboard = poll()
keyboard.register(stdin)

Key = ''

while True:
    
    if uart.any():
        data = uart.read()
        Data2 = data.decode('ascii') # read mesages from motor and decodes them to ascii 
        print(Data2 + "\r")
        
    elif keyboard.poll(0):  # if key is pressed
        key2 = stdin.read(1)  # read one character until '0a' is found
        hex = key2.encode("utf-8").hex()  # this convers charactes to hex. we are looking for 'enter'
        if  hex != '0a':


"I can not stop the loop if ..." - Then you've coded the loop improperly, i.e. it's a bug. Don't blame the "UART" or the data flow for your problem. Seems like the if uart.any(): is problematic. BTW apparently the underlying OS is Linux. Your program is not bare-metal and/or accessing the hardware directly. There are several layers of software processing (and buffers) between the actual UART and your Python code. Your Python code merely fetches data from a system buffer rather than directly from a "UART".

Hi sawdust, I am not blaming UART I am sure that it is my coding but I can not think or find a way to do it right. I did similar type of code in full python which has much more libraries and I could find function to suit. But in micropython I can not find the simple / good way to do it.

"I can not think or find a way to do it right." - What have you tried? One more time:  the if uart.any(): seems problematic. Why do you use if ... elif ...? Why does one condition exclude the other, in other words use if ... if ...?

Thank you for help. the If .. if does not even occur to me.  I will definitely change that. Regarding what I have tried. I have mainly investigate the keyboard.poll. Try to understand it but obviously failed. As I mentioned I tried to use equivalent to  msvcrt.kbhit() which is monitor the keyboard key and raise the interrupt. But I did not find way to do it with stdin.

@sawdust the Raspberry Pi Pico is a microcontroller and does not have an OS.
